# Javascript object.style.color not working in create.js.erb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Please view the create.js.erb code below which fades in a new vote when its created. I would like to have the color of the total number of votes change when the value is below 0.

The code below works if I exchange .style.color for .css("color", "orange"); however I would like the change to be permanent.

```
<% if @vote.new_record? %>
alert("Failed to create vote: <%= j @vote.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>
var votes = $("<h1><%= @vote.votable.votes_count %></h1>");
<% if @vote.votable.votes_count < 0 %>
$('#<%= "#{votes_count}_#{id}" %>').style.color = "#FF8800";
<% end %>
$('#<%= "#{votes_count}_#{id}" %>').html(votes.fadeIn(1000));
<% end %>
```

When .style.color is used the fadeIn code isn't called an the vote doesn't show.

Why is style.color not working in this instance?

**EDIT**

thanks to the comments from anspnm I have changed the offending line to:

```
document.getElementById('<%= "#{votes_count}_#{id}" %>').className += " orange-arrows h1";
```

which works and changes the color of the vote text however, this color still isn't persisted and dissapears when the browser refreshes.

Comment: If you check console, you get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined `. `style` is not a property of the jQuery object. `document.getElementById("test").style.color = "#FF8800";` << this would work as style is a property of DOM object.

Comment: ive replaced the line with document.getElementById('<%= "#{votes_count}_#{id}" %>').style.color = "#FF8800"; and the vote now fades in however the color isn't applied

Comment: Try a static id instead of `"#{votes_count}_#{id}" ` and see if that works

Comment: Yeah i just tried question-comments and the style.color works however, it doesn't persist on page loads, is this supposed to be the case?

Comment: Oh in that case you need to have a class defined for this color in CSS and on load check if vote_count > 0  then give class `orange` else give class `default` as dynamic style would go away when you refresh

Comment: thanks for your help anpsmn on this, i have done that which works using the following document.getElementById('<%= "#{votes_count}_#{id}" %>').className += " orange-arrows h1"; however again the color doesn't persist?

Comment: No, what I  meant was when you render the element keep a check if votecount exist something like this `<div class="<%= @vote.votable.votes_count < 0 ? 'default-arrows' : 'orange-arrows' %>">` and for the ajax call use this `$('#<%= "#{votes_count}_#{id}" %>').addClass('orange-arrows')`

Comment: _"however, this color still isn't persisted and dissapears when the browser refreshes."_ - of course it does, why would you expect something different?

Comment: put this in an answer @anpsmn and ill gladly mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On load when you render the element keep a check if vote count exists.

Something like this

```
<div class="<%= @vote.votable.votes_count < 0 ? 'default-arrows' : 'orange-arrows' %>">
```

So on page refresh the check will take care of the color on basis of the vote_count.

And for the ajax call use this, which will take care of the newly created element through ajax

```
$('#<%= "#{votes_count}_#{id}" %>').addClass('orange-arrows')
```